# Editar snippets de LaTeX en Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3, latex

En el siguiente `snippet` del paquete `LaTeX` *(Sublime Text 3)* cada vez que ingreso un `espacio`, `*`, `?` o `.` en la parte de:

```
label{sec:*********} y  % section ********* (end)
```

sustituye los caracteres mencionados por el underline `_`.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
\section{${1:section name}} % (fold)
\label{sec:${2:${1/\\\w+\{(.*?)\}|\\(.)|(\w+)|([^\w\\]+)/(?4:_:\L$1$2$3)/g}}}
${0:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}
% section $2 (end)]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>sec</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
    <description>Section</description>
</snippet>
```

Entonces, mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo se puede modificar el `snippet` para que reemplace las vocales con tilde por una vocal sin tilde?**

Es decir: si ingreso `á`, `é`, `í`, `ó` y `ú` que lo sustituya por `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` y `u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresión regular te permite capturar los grupos y especificar el reemplazo de cada uno, intenta el siguiente `snippet`:

> Nota: He situado grupos de captura hasta el número 6, si deseas añadir otro reemplazo, añade seguido de un `pipe|` otro grupo `(G)` donde `G` es el patrón a buscar y después sitúa el reemplazo al final con la notación `(?N:R)` donde `N` es el número del grupo y `R` el reemplazo.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
\section{${1:section name}} % (fold)
\label{sec:${2:${1/(?:([^\w])|(á)|(é)|(í)|(ó)|(ú))/(?1:_)(?2:a)(?3:e)(?4:i)(?5:o)(?6:u)/g}}}
${0:$SELECTION}
% section $2 (end)]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>sec</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
    <description>Section</description>
</snippet>
```